# See JSON on Cloud 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, cloud9-ide

I am using Cloud 9 for my ruby on rails app instead of local server. This link below said we can see the JSON with (name-of-json).json in the local, but i can't do the same here.

If i am using cloud 9, what should the path be for me to see the json?

http://blog.crowdint.com/2014/02/18/fancy-calendars-for-your-web-application-with-fullcalendar.html

I am using Cloud 9 instead of local server. This link below

Answer (score 0):

This should show up in your workspace directory: `/home/ubuntu/workspace`

Comment: To clarify, you mean /home/ubuntu/workspace/(name).JSON?

Comment: Well yes, this would be the name of the file but I meant to phrase it ("this would show up in") as the directory where it would be stored. Semantics :)